# How to aggregate analytics from Google, Twitter, YouTube, Facebook, etc

Tags: twitter, google-analytics, youtube, analytics, aggregation

I have a video blog for which I would like to track certain statistics, including stats from Google Analytics, Twitter, YouTube, Facebook, etc.

The problem is that the various stats are on different websites, which require different logins, etc. It takes a long time to actually view everything. I am looking for a way to be able to aggregate all of this information in one place.

I have searched quite a bit on Google, Mashable, Delicious, etc and I haven't found any websites that do what I want. Are my searching skills bad, or does this really not exist?

The data in which I am interested appears to be available in readily parsable forms (see below), but I am hesitant to write an app to do this myself, because of an already more than full workload.

Data I want to aggregate:

- Google Analytics -- tracking on my website

  - number of visitors
  - traffic sources
  - use Data Export API -- http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html
- Twitter

  - number of followers
  - number of retweets
  - new @ messages
  - new direct messages
  - Twitter API -- (sorry, I can only post one hyperlink because I am new)
- Facebook fan page

  - number of fans
  - new posts on wall
  - Facebook API -- (sorry, I can only post one hyperlink because I am new)
- Tumblr

  - number of followers
- Video

  - number of views
  - view location
  - number of comments
  - number of channel subscribers
  - do this for

    - YouTube -- CSV report available at (sorry, I can only post one hyperlink because I am new)
    - MetaCritic
- Feed burner (RSS)

  - number of subscribers
  - CSV report available at (sorry, I can only post one hyperlink because I am new)
- SEO stuff

  - Google PageRank
  - Alexa rankings

So is there an app that does this already, or should I do this myself? I would like a quick and dirty way to do this -- I was thinking something like Yahoo pipes, but it appears to not be up to the task. I could probably get it done in Grails, but that might be more trouble than it's worth. Other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have a better answer. YQL has community data tables for all the services you listed. You can pull in all the different values through their API.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a Google Spreadsheet and use their external data import tools.

http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75507

The biggest problem will probably be access authenticated APIs.

Comment: abraham, I'm not sure which data import tools you are talking about. Do you mean inserting something via the insert -> gadget menu? There don't appear to be any gadgets for any of the data sources in which I'm interested. Most of these APIs appear to require some real code. That is why I have rejected using Yahoo pipes too.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will be able to collect all of this data without some real code. If you are lucky there might be a startup out there that has built this exact product but I doubt it. =importXML("URL","query") is a spreadsheet function that could pull in data from the third-parties to be collected for your use.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably that all of the services above has fashioned a statistics API, I would advice you to write it yourself rather than battling an integration war with a bunch of aggregating programs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an iphone app that does at least a bit of this:

http://ego-app.com/

Comment: It looks like that app would do some of what I would like. Unfortunately, I don't have an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a single tool that can do this, off the top of my head. But you can chain a few tools together to do this.

1- If you're on Windows, use Website Watcher. It has a macro-recording tool to login a webpage, a regex-based tool to filter content and a scripting language that let you email/export the result. IMO, this will let you extract data from just any web page/RSS/forums.

2- Then use Dropbox to automatically upload the result files to your Dropbox's public folder (because you will need the public link to these file).

3- Use Yahoo Pipes to consolidate/aggregate the result files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try Metricly http://metricly.com/ that is natively intergating Facebook & Google Analytics data. It is extensible by nature and with a little bit of tweaking you can push any meric to it. I enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

I originally suggested this as an edit to abraham's answer but it was rejected:

Mikael Thuneberg has written a freely available google script for pulling GA data into Google Docs using the GA API: http://www.automateanalytics.com/2010/04/google-analytics-data-to-google-docs.html

I use it for creating client dashboards all the time. I suspect there may be others for pulling in twitter/facebook data etc.

And Google have just released this tool for importing GA data into Google Docs:
http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/automate-google-analytics-reporting.html

Also see SEOTools for Excel which can pull some facebook and twitter data as well as Google Analytics through the API.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has a public API http://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics to retrieve reports for your videos and channels.